# Partition of a lower and upper sum in Riemann Integration.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

I am trying to show that the for a refinement $P_0$ in the partition P then this inequality holds.
$L(f,P) ≤ L(f,P_
0
) ≤ U(f,P_
0
) ≤ U(f,P)$.
I understand that a refinement will make our estimate more accurate and thus the infimum will be larger and similarly for the supremum but I am unsure how to go about showing that it is the case.

If this question has already been asked please feel free to send a link.

Comment: Consider that $P=[p_0,p_n]$ is refined to $P'=[p_0,p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n]$. Consider the maximum value of $f$ in each smaller interval $[p_i,p_{i+1}]$. How do they compare with that of $[p_0,p_n]?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all partitions and refinements are finite, you can assume the refinement is by a single point (continue by induction).
Let $P = \{x_1,..., x_n\}$ be a partition, $f(x_i^*) := \inf_{x \in [x_{i-1}, x_i]}f(x)$ and suppose $P_0$ is the refinement of $P$ by adding $x_{k-1} < z < x_k$ then we have:
$$L(f,P) = \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i^*) \Delta x_i \\
= \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} f(x_i^*) \Delta x_i + \sum_{i=k+1}^n f(x_i^*) \Delta x_i + f(x_k^*) (x_k - x_{k-1} + z - z)\\
\leq \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} f(x_i^*) \Delta x_i + \sum_{i=k+1}^n f(x_i^*) \Delta x_i + \inf_{x \in [x_{k-1}, z]}f(x) (z- x_{k-1}) +  \inf_{x \in [z, x_{k}]}f(x) (x_k - z)\\
= L(f, P_0)$$

Same argument works for $U(f,P)$.